# Explicit move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, explicit-constructor, move-constructor

The `explicit` keyword is recommended for <strike>all</strike> *most* constructors which **can be called with one argument**, except for copy constructors.

For **copy constructors**, it has an use (to forbid implicit copying via function call, return, etc), but it's not what's usually wanted.

What about **move constructors**? Is there any reasonable use case to make them explicit? What's the good practice here?

Comment: What is the difference between a "copy constructor" and a "constructor that can be called with one argument"? I just had a moments confusion with DeadMGs answer because I thought these were the same thing. This *is* just the way it's used, and (other than "explicit") not how the constructor is declared, yes? Or have I gone insane?

Comment: @Steve314: A single-argument copy constructor is specifically a constructor `T([const] [volatile] T&)`. 12.8/2. `T(int)` is a constructor that can be called with one argument, but is not a copy constructor because it doesn't "copy" an instance of `T`.

Comment: @Steve Jessop - yes, of course. Obviously I have gone brain dead.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! So can we agree that there's no reasonable (i.e. beneficial in an obvious way) reason to make it explicit?

Comment: It's also recommended for constructors which can only be called for multiple arguments in C++0x.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub, you mean there are cases in C++0x when the `explicit` keyword would make a difference on such constructors? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

An `explicit` move constructors can affect compatibility with e.g. Standard algorithms. For instance, `std::swap<T>` requires that `T` be MoveConstructible. In turn, MoveConstructible is specified in terms of an expression, namely `T u = rv;` (where `rv` is an rvalue of type `T`).

If there is neither a non-explicit copy constructor nor a non-explicit move constructor for a given type then `T u = rv;` is invalid and that type can't be used with `std::swap`. (In this particular instance however it is possible to specialize `std::swap` to provide the desired functionality, e.g. by using `T u(rv);`).

Put more simply, an `explicit` move or copy constructor defies expectations and can't be used as well with generic code.

Some other parts of the Standard library that put a MoveConstructible requirement:

- the deleter of `unique_ptr<T, D>`
- call wrappers, used in e.g. `bind` (all the decayed types that are passed are concerned)
- `thread`, `async`, `call_once` (all specified in terms of call wrappers)
- `sort`, `stable_sort`, `nth_element`, `sort_heap`

Answer (score 7):

You probably want an implicit move constructor for the majority of uses. They generally fall into the same categories as copy constructors. Explicit isn't recommended for *all* one-argument constructors, but it is recommended for most. Move constructors are not on that list.

Answer (score 7):

The `explicit` keyword is recommended for (single argument) *converting* constructors, to avoid surprising conversions in unexpected places.

Copy constructors and move constructors are hardly "surprising" in that sense. They happen largely where expected. If you don't want them, I would expect them to be marked `=delete` rather than made explicit.

Answer (score 3):

The actual question is how explicit move constructor could possibly be used? It wouldn't be able to be invoked on rvalues, so compiler would have to always select a copy constructor, if available, or fail to compile.

Edit: here is the link to example: http://www.ideone.com/nm7KM

Comment: @Luc: it's a good one! and probably the only way explicit move constructor can be invoked.

Comment: +1 for a good question, Gene :) And more props for Luc for the answer (it could be useful if you would add it to your post for any future reference). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When returning by value from a function, an implicit move constructor can usually make the process more efficient.

Comment: A bit off-topic but good point, actually- I think that's a reason to make move constructors inline if possible.